# Can water be magnetized?

Tags: electromagnetism, condensed-matter, levitation

This may be a stupid question, so feel free to shoot it down.

Assuming all atoms have a magnetic moment, I would assume the water molecule too would have a resultant magnetic moment; ergo, it may be possible to magnetize a body of water.

Can water be magnetized?

Comment: Hello @Everyone, [Here's](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=406323) a page for you in which they're talking about the subject... Do you mean *ferromagnetic*..?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Water is a diamagnetic material and like most other non-ferromagnetic materials it does interact with magnetic fields but with much weaker interactions than you are used to from fridge magnets and the like. However, if you crank up the field to something like hundreds of thousands of the Earth's magnetic field - about 10 Tesla will do - then you do get sizable forces that can compare with the weight of the water.

Since all living beings contain a large fraction of water, this was used with considerable impact by Michael Berry and Andre Geim to [levitate frogs](http://www.ru.nl/hfml/research/levitation/diamagnetic/) as a demonstration of the effect that took most physicists by surprise, and which [won them an Ig Nobel prize](http://www.improbable.com/2010/10/05/geim-becomes-first-nobel-ig-nobel-winner/) back in 2000.

[image: Frog levitating]

Pictures are nice, but the really striking thing is to watch it [on video](http://www.youtube.com/results?q=levitating+frog).

Answer (score -2):

Pass a lot of electricity through a small amount of water(behaves as an electric conductor). There will be field around it. If you want to have magnetism for a non-electrocuted water, its impossible(to get higher B values). But, using some solutes you can increase the magnetic property of water.